# $k$ ordered sums of a natural number

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $k, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that we have $n > k$. My question is: In how many ordered ways can we write $n$ as sum of the natural numbers $k, k + 1, k + 2, \ldots, n$? No number less than $k$ can be used in the sum.

For example if we take $n = 10$ and $k = 2$, then we can write $10$ in $5$ ordered ways using the numbers $3,4,5,6,7,8, 9, 10$. These are

$$10 = 10 \qquad 10 = 5 + 5 \qquad 10 = 6 + 4 \qquad 10 = 7 + 3 \qquad 10 = 3 + 3 + 4$$

I have tried this for a long time and got a way to do this using the stars and bars concept, however the closed form which we get from the stars and bars seems to be very painful to evaluate for some large value of $n$ and hence I was looking for a more nice approach with a nice closed form.

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can try constructing the recursion of $A_{n,k}$,where $A_{n,k}$ is the number of the ordered way?

Comment: @JwJJJJ I tried recurrence but I don't think it helps to get a nice closed form. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clearly formulated: $n$ can hardly ever be written as sum of **the** numbers $k,k+1,\ldots,n$, and in any case that sum has just one value (which is usually larger than $n$). What you appear to mean is in how many ways $n$ can be written as sum of a multiset of natural numbers, all of them at least $k$.

Comment: I think my original question makes sense. What's wrong with it?  I don't know what a multiset is.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I think it is more conventional to say this is the number of partitions of $n$ where the smallest part is at least $k$

Comment: Your question refers to "ordered ways" which suggest that for $n = 10$ and $k = 3$ there are 9 solutions: $10, 7+3, 6+4, 5+5, 4+6, 4 + 3 + 3, 3+7, 3+4+3, 3+3+4$.  Is this what you intended?  Henry's answer is about integer partitions while the question seems to be about integer compositions.

Answer (score 1):

This is [OEIS A026807](https://oeis.org/A026807).  I doubt there is a closed form.

One way of finding this is to say
$$A_{n,k}=\left\{\begin{matrix} 0 &\text{ when }&n<k \\
1 &\text{ when }&k \le n \lt 2k \\ 
A_{n-k,k}+A_{n,k+1} &\text{ when }&2k \le n 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

since you can either have a partition of a smaller number plus the smallest extra part, or a partition of the same number with a larger minimum part, but once you are looking at a minimum part more than half the number you can only have the number itself.

So in your example, with $n=10, k=3$: $A_{10,3} $ $=A_{7,3}+A_{10,4}$ $=A_{4,3}+A_{7,4}+A_{6,4}+A_{10,5}$ $=A_{4,3}+A_{7,4}+A_{6,4}+A_{5,5}+A_{10,6}$ $=1+1+1+1+1 = 5$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to give a closed form? Also this doesn't seem to give recurrence too?

Comment: @Permutator Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  I said "I doubt there is a closed form", but I think I have given an elegant recurrence and explanation as well as a link to more references

Comment: Yeah but can we solve the recurrence you have given? I don't think so

Comment: It can be applied to any positive values of $n$ and $k$.  Indeed I did so for your example.  Note that $A_{n,1}$ is simply the [number of partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) of $n$ and that does not have a closed form.

Comment: Alright, let's make this more simpler. What if I fix $k = 2$? Can you give me a nice closed form for all $n$?

Comment: No - if I could give a closed form for $A_{n,2}$ then I could probably also do so for $A_{n,1}$. Cleverer people then me such as Hardy/Ramanujan/Rademacher/Erdős did not find one for that, probably because it may not exist.  There will be approximations

Comment: Isn't $A_{n, 2}$ this sequence https://oeis.org/A318196?

Comment: No. $A_{n,2}$ is [OEIS A002865](https://oeis.org/A002865), while $A_{n,3}$ is [OEIS A008483](https://oeis.org/A008483).  None of these give closed forms

Comment: But if I calculate $A_{n,2}$ for small $n$, then I'm getting the sequence https://oeis.org/A318196. Is something wrong with my question?

Comment: Consider the first case where they differ: $A_{7,2}=4$ not $5$ since you have $7=5+2=4+3=3+2+2$